# HQL group by problem when dealing with inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Lets say I have entity `Parent` and entity `Child extends Parent`.  When I write HQL to select `Parent`, hibernate tries to select also `Child` by adding join to `Child` with projection, which **breaks** `group by` contract of the original query written in HQL.

Model

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Entity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id; 
    ...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Parent extends Entity { ... }

@Entity
public class Child extends Parent { ... }
```

HQL query

```
select p 
from Parent p
...
group by p;
```

Translated query

```
select p_.*, 
       c_.*, 
       case 
           when c_.id is not null then 1 
           when p_.id is not null then 0 
       end as clazz_,
from parent p_ 
left inner join child c_ on (p_.id = c_.id) 
... 
group by p_.id;
```

SQLGrammarException

> column c_... must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an
>   aggregate function

**Hibernate 5.2.1.Final**

Comment: Are you sure the data model is correct? I think a child has a parent, but not every child is a parent. That is what is implied by your current data model.

Comment: @MichielLeegwater entity model included.

Comment: Why do you need to group by parent? In this case it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @AlexeyVlasov in real use-case, I have also other entities in projection/group by, but here to keep things simple I have included only parent.